# Change sum depending on checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a span where on initial load the sum is displayed of all the checkboxes (all checked). When unchecking one of the checkbox, the value within that checkbox should be decreased from the sum. I have tried this, but in stead of decreasing that value, when unchecking it is doubling the value. E.g. of the checked values: 42,13,100 = 155, unchecking 42 should give 113 but is resulting in 310.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/6/

```
var sum = 0;
$('.numbers').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($.text(this), 10);
});

$(".total").text(sum);


$('.checkbox').change(function () {
       //assign
       var sumChange = 0;    

      //for each checked checkbox
      $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
          $('.numbers').each(function() {
              sumChange += parseInt($.text(this), 10);
          });
      });

       $(".total").text(sumChange);

  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd change your change function to:

```
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
    //assign
    var sumChange = 0;
    //for each checked checkbox
    $('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
            sumChange += parseInt($(this).parent().text(), 10);
    });
    $(".total").text(sumChange);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M7ghD/7/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M7ghD/8/
Slight variant on the above.  Not parsing through the DOM each time. No big deal.